# Unable to understand why the code is not giving the desired outcome?

Tags: python, apache, web-applications, cgi, server-side

I am trying to make a simple webapp based on Head First Python book. But the python cgi script embedded in index.html file instead of generating a html page after clicking on the hyperlink, is giving back the code of python cgi script. I have tried searching for the reason of why this is happening, but no luck. It will really be helpful if somebody can tell me why this problem is occurring ?
Here is the index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Welcome to Coach Kelly's Website</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/coach.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="images/coach-head.jpg">
    <h1>Welcome to Coach Kelly's Website.</h1>
    <p>
        For now, all that you'll find here is my athlete's <a href="cgi-bin/generate_list.py">timing data</a>. Enjoy!
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>See you on the track!</strong>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the cgi script:

```html
import athletemodel
import yate
import glob

data_files = glob.glob("data/*.txt")
athletes = athletemodel.put_to_store(data_files)

print(yate.start_response())
print(yate.include_header("Coach Kelly's List of Athletes"))
print(yate.start_form("generate_timing_data.py"))
print(yate.para("Select an athlete from the list to work with:"))

for each_athlete in athletes:
    print(yate.radio_button("which_athlete", athletes[each_athlete].name))

print(yate.end_form("Select"))

print(yate.include_footer({"Home": "/index.html"}))
```

Here is the yate.py :

```html
from string import Template

def start_response(resp="text/html"):
    return('Content-type: ' + resp + '\n\n')

def include_header(the_title):
    with open('templates/header.html') as headf:
        head_text = headf.read()
    header = Template(head_text)
    return(header.substitute(title=the_title))

def include_footer(the_links):
    with open('templates/footer.html') as footf:
        foot_text = footf.read()
    link_string = ''
    for key in the_links:
        link_string += '<a href="' + the_links[key] + '">' + key + '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    footer = Template(foot_text)
    return(footer.substitute(links=link_string))

def start_form(the_url, form_type="POST"):
    return('<form action="' + the_url + '" method="' + form_type + '">')

def end_form(submit_msg="Submit"):
    return('<p></p><input type=submit value="' + submit_msg + '"></form>')

def radio_button(rb_name, rb_value):
    return('<input type="radio" name="' + rb_name +
                             '" value="' + rb_value + '"> ' + rb_value + '<br />')

def u_list(items):
    u_string = '<ul>'
    for item in items:
        u_string += '<li>' + item + '</li>'
    u_string += '</ul>'
    return(u_string)

def header(header_text, header_level=2):
    return('<h' + str(header_level) + '>' + header_text +
           '</h' + str(header_level) + '>')

def para(para_text):
    return('<p>' + para_text + '</p>')
```

Her is the code to create a web server:

```html
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

port = 8080

httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
print("Starting simple_httpd on port: " + str(httpd.server_port))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I am attaching images of actual output after clicking on hyperlink vs what I am getting.
Home page:
[image: Home page for webapp]

After clicking on timing data, I should get this:
[image: Actual output]

Output I am getting:
[image: Output I am getting.]

Comment: Code [here](https://github.com/ericjankowski/python/tree/master/bookExamples/headFirstPython/chapter_7/webapp) looks very similar to your with difference that you cgi python file don't have shebang line `#! /usr/local/bin/python3`. Also check if that file have execute permission if not give it with `chmod +x filename`

Comment: But I am working in windows . What you are mentioning , is for linux environment.

Comment: So I got [this code](https://github.com/ericjankowski/python/tree/master/bookExamples/headFirstPython/chapter_7/webapp) and replaced all files with your code and everything works fine on Windows machine, cgi is rendered as expected. Could you try copying  that github repo code yourself (by making new fresh project) to rule out mistakes in other files?

Comment: I tried , it's not working .